# What is a word or phrase for someone who does shift work alone?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

The kind of worker (shift worker) who to do all job alone without co-worker, like someone who works in such fast food or retail but he got the single person shift. Is there any specific term about that. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Trooper? Veteran? Hero? One-man band?

Comment: The term is [**lone worker**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_worker).